Change product varation price programatically based on a custom field in WooCommerce
I have some variable products that have a custom field "base price". I want to change the variation price only in single product, cart and checkout pages that should affect original prices.
Lets assume, I have a variable product with one variation priced $10 and the "base price" custom field value is 200.
So, In frontend this variation price should be $2000 ( $10 x 200 ), but in admin panel, the variation price should stay at 10$.
I used this code:
// Function to calculate custom price based on variation
function custom_variation_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    // Check if it's a variable product
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        // Get all available variations
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();       
        // Get the base price
        $base_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_base_price', true );
        // Check if base price is set and greater than 0
        if ( isset( $base_price ) && $base_price > 0 ) {
            foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
                // Get the variation object
                $variation_obj = wc_get_product( $variation['variation_id'] );
                // Get the regular price of the variation
                $regular_price = $variation_obj->get_price();
                // Calculate the custom price
                $custom_price = floatval( $regular_price ) * $base_price;
                // Format the custom price
                $formatted_price = wc_price( $custom_price );
                // Replace the variation price in the price HTML
                $price_html = str_replace( wc_price( $regular_price ), $formatted_price, $price_html );
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the modified price HTML
    return $price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_variation_price_html', 10, 2 );

And this is the result I have in frontend:

Only the variable product price range is affected, I also want the selected variation price to be changed.

You are not using the correct way and the required hooks…
Context: If I understand well you have a custom field _base_price in your variable products, something like as the following (just for testing):
// Add a custom field to variable product in backend
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_custom_variable_product_option_pricing' );
function add_custom_variable_product_option_pricing() {
    echo '</div>
    <div class="options_group  pricing show_if_variable" >';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_base_price',
        'label'         => __('Base price rate', 'woocommerce'),
        'data_type'     => 'price,'
    ));
}

// Save variable product custom submitted value in Backend
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_custom_variable_product_option_pricing', 30, 1 );
function save_custom_variable_product_option_pricing( $product ){
    if ( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) return;
    $base_price = isset($_POST['_base_price']) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash($_POST['_base_price']) ) : null;
    $product->update_meta_data('_base_price', $base_price );
}


Based on Change product prices via a hook in WooCommerce 3+ answer code, you will use the following code replacement instead:
// Change product variation prices
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
function custom_price( $price, $variation ) {
    $product    = wc_get_product($variation->get_parent_id());
    $base_price = (float) $product->get_meta('_base_price');

    if ( $price > 0 && $base_price > 0 ) {
        return $price * $product->get_meta('_base_price');
    }
}

// Change variable product price range
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variable_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_variable_price', 99, 3 );
function custom_variable_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    $base_price = (float) $product->get_meta('_base_price');

    if ( $price > 0 && $base_price > 0 ) {
        return $price * $product->get_meta('_base_price');
    }
}

// Handling price caching
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash', 'add_price_multiplier_to_variation_prices_hash', 99, 3 );
function add_price_multiplier_to_variation_prices_hash( $price_hash, $product, $for_display ) {
    $base_price = (float) $product->get_meta('_base_price');

    if ( $base_price > 0 ) {
        $price_hash[] = $base_price;
    }
    return $price_hash;
}

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.
